# Validation: satisfy any one of the rules, not all of them

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have two validation rules that I want to apply to the 'metric_id' field:

```
$rules = ['metric_id' => 'exists:metrics,id|in:foo,bar'];
```

But instead of having to satisfy both rules, I want to satisfy one **or** the other (either exists in metrics table or is a specified value).

How do I do this? Do I have to make a custom validation rule?

Comment: Try to call wanted `$rules` dynamically per situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do it is:

```
$metric_id_passes = 
Validator::make([Input::get('metric_id')], ['metric_id' => 'exists:metrics,id'])->passes() 
||
Validator::make([Input::get('metric_id'), ['metric_id' => 'in:foo,bar']])->passes();
```

Or you can wrap it in a custom validation rule:

```
Validator::extend('MetricIDExistsOrIn', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    return Validator::make(['metric_id' => 'exists:metrics,id'], [ $value ])->passes() ||
           Validator::make(['metric_id' => 'in:foo,bar'], [$value])->passes();
});

$rules = ['metric_id' => 'MetricIDExistsOrIn'];
```